# How do I position a texture image in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I have a sphere with an earth texture on it. I can plot exact points on the sphere but need to adjust the position of the texture (rotate it) to match where the coordinates will be placed. Is there a way to rotate the texture on a sphere?

Comment: Do you want to rotate it around the Y axis only?

Comment: yes, but it would be helpful it i could also rotate it around the X as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try playing with this:

```
texture.offset.x = 0.5; // 0.0 - 1.0
texture.offset.y = 0.5; // 0.0 - 1.0
```

Comment: perfect! what kind of increment is that?

Comment: It's `0.5 * image.width` for the `x` and `0.5 * image.height` for the `y`;

Comment: @mrdoob hi there, total webGL newbie. 
I tried the offset you suggested but I’m finding that it leaves a line down the middle of my cube. 
I’ve seen people get around this by using a custom shader but that breaks the code elsewhere. 
Is there any native three.js workaround to this problem?

Thanks. You’re awesome btw.